# gamma and beta function relation

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

I am reading [this](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~kulis/teaching/788_sp12/DP.learnalpha.pdf), and don't understand how this is reached $$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha+n)}=\frac{(\alpha+n)\beta(\alpha+1,n)}{\alpha\Gamma(n)}$$

The following relation mentioned on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function),$$\beta(\alpha,n)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(\alpha+n)} \Rightarrow \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha+n)}=\frac{\beta(\alpha,n)}{\Gamma(n)}$$

so given the above two, this must be true, $$\frac{(\alpha+n)\beta(\alpha+1,n)}{\alpha\Gamma(n)}=\frac{\beta(\alpha,n)}{\Gamma(n)}$$
which means this also must be true, $$\frac{(\alpha+n)\beta(\alpha+1,n)}{\alpha}=\beta(\alpha,n)$$. I can't see why this is true, given the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) of the $\beta$ function.

Comment: Use the fact that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)\Gamma(n-1)$ on the expanded $\beta(\alpha+1,n)$

Comment: This could be on topic on the [math.SE] SE site, but is also on topic here, IMO. We can defer to the OP's preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last statement you have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{(\alpha+n)\beta(\alpha+1,n)}{\alpha} = \beta(\alpha,n)
\end{equation}
is true if you expand $\beta(\alpha+1,n)$ as $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1+n)}$ then follow @ArtificialBreeze's suggestion. Here it is

\begin{split}
\frac{(\alpha+n)\beta(\alpha+1,n)}{\alpha} & = \frac{(\alpha+n)\color{red}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\Gamma(n)}{\alpha\color{blue}{\Gamma(\alpha+1+n)}} \\
&= \frac{(\alpha+n)\color{red}{[\alpha\times\Gamma(\alpha)]}\Gamma(n)}{\alpha\color{blue}{[(\alpha+n)\Gamma(\alpha+n)]}} \\
\end{split}

Cancelling out terms will result in $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(\alpha+n)}$, which is what you have above.